# How to get labels of elements by their IDs with Selenium Webdriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have drop-downs that have assigned IDs and each of them has a name visible in the UI. Below is an example. The ID of the drop-down is `Filter_Comparison`, its label in the UI is 'Primary Comparison', and the label is described as `<label for="Filter_Comparison">Primary Comparison</label>`. How can I grab the text of that label by the ID that it is assigned to?

[image]

[image]

Sure enough the following is not going to work as it is going to give the text of the option that is currently selected in the drop-down (in this case it is 'Benchmark Focused'):

```
browser.find_element_by_id(`Filter_Comparison`).text
```

Comment: //*[@id='Filter_Comparison']/following-sibling::lable -- you can try this  browser.find_element_by_xpath(`//*[@id='Filter_Comparison']/following-sibling::lable`).text

Comment: I assume you mean `//*[@id='Filter_Comparison']/following-sibling::label`. I tried it, and I get `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='Filter_Comparison']/following-sibling::label"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute `for` in the label already is `id` of dropdown, you can use it.

```
filterComparisonId = 'Filter_Comparison'
filterComparison = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('label[for="'+ filterComparisonId +'"]').text
filterComparisonElement = browser.find_element_by_id(filterComparisonId)
```